# Edit person.aspx?

Tags: user-profile-service, feature, my-site, feature-activation, welcome-page

We have more than 1000 user profiles that need a customized person.aspx. We need to make quite big changes to person.aspx. What is best practice here ? Do we edit person.aspx via SharePoint designer or is it better to provision  a custom page layout and set it as welcome page ?

Is it possible to have features activate automatically when a new my site is created ?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to

1. Create a Visual Studio Solution.
2. Then add your page layouts and other styling files.
3. Create a feature receiver
4. Use that to set the Page or create new page using the custom layout etc.

For existing site, you can deploy the solution and then use PowerShell to activate it on all the sites.

Comment: I am aware of this approach. What I am trying to know is if this is good to with my site. Also, I am trying to find out how features can activate when a new my site is created without manually running a powershell script.